# C++ static and shared libraries

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, static-libraries

I would like to create a static library in C++ to store my functions.
I'm aware this question has been asked on the Cplusplus forums but I could really use a
more accurate description of what to do.

As far as I'm aware you create a new Win32 program and then add the header file (.h) and the
code file (.cpp).

So in fact I have a few questions.

1 - How do I put my code into these files?
    Do I use the .cpp?

2 - I did manage to make a simple library with an add function alone, but after compiling
    and building it I was unable to #include it in a program. Why is this?

Could someone please write out a step-by-step approach to making this so I can finally do it.
I am aware MSDN has a tutorial for this, and I have looked at it.
The thing is it uses a OOP approach to making the static library, and the calls to the
functions within the library use the  :: operator (think its an operator), too often which is what I want to avoid.
Would like to start simple, basically.

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: I've added the `windows` and `visual-c++` tags; I assume this is correct?  If not please edit them yourself.

Comment: To use a static library in another project you have to include the headers file and link to the *.lib file that is generated by the library.

Comment: How do you do that?
I know you #include "yourlibrary.h"
but how do you link to the .lib file & where is this file located?

Comment: The .lib file is located in your output folder of the compiled library. Usually bin/debug or bin/release.

Comment: What IDE are you using? I can help you with code::blocks, but not with anything else. Visual studio has a good walkthrough though.

Comment: I like code::blocks, but I'm using Visual Studio, sorry.
Please don't give me an MSDN link.
I could really use a step-by-step that someone has made themselves, for implementing this.
I'm not completely thick, that being said I wish this was easier...

Comment: Alright, I'll see if I can help you with Visual Studio anyway. Did you manage to compile your library?

Comment: The library is incredibly simple, it just adds two numbers.
Was just trying to get something working.
So yeh, it compiled without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a static library, is that you write your code as usual, but you compile it as a static library. The users of a static library still need your header files, but they don't need your .CPP files anymore, because the actual implementation is contained in your static library file.

To use a library, you include the header files you need, and then link the library file with your program.

Here is a link to the microsoft walkthrough.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235627.aspx

**How to create and use a static library using Visual Studio**

Here is excactly how you do it in Visual Studio 2012.

- To create a library, create a new C++ project. In the wizard, at Application Settings, choose Static library. Uncheck Precompiled header.
- Create your library as you want. Don't forget to declare everything in header files.
- Compile the project as you usually would. This creates a .lib file in the debug folder of your **solution**
- To use the library, create an application as you usually would.
- To link the library with your project, drag the .lib file to your project in visual studio.
- To let visual studio find your header files, right click your project. Choose Properties->Configuration properties->C/C++. There is a input box called Additional Include Directories. Here, you have to write the path to the header files of you library.

You can now use the header files as if they where made by your project directly. The implementation of your library is taken from the .lib file, and everything should compile and run well.

Another option, is referencing the whole libary project in your application. To do this, you must get the library project in your solution. Right click your solution in Visual Studio->Add->Existing Project. Then you have to reference the project. Right click your project->References->Common Properties->Framework and References->Add New Reference->Choose your project. Now you can edit your library in this solution and use it directly in your application.

Comment: Thanks.
I've been looking at that stupid MSDN link all day, but I appreciate it nonetheless.
I write my code in the .h (header)?
So when doing this do I need to #include any other libraries my code needs?

Comment: Do you write all of your code in .h files? If this is true, you should learn to properly use header files and .cpp files. This is very important. If you compile as a library, you will still need to include your header files. And yes, if your library depends on other libraries, you will have to link with those as well.

Comment: No I don't, I was asking Aart if that was correct because I didn't believe it was true.
From what I know you write the definitions of any functions in the .cpp file.
Like I previously mentioned, despite even having a book on this, there is never a clear indication of what you need to do to make a static library.

I'm trying to do it at the moment with the .h file linked to my program.
How do I add the .cpp to the program?
MSDN talks about changing the references through the IDE?

Comment: Aart and me are the same person :p It is still not clear to me. Do you write all your code in your header files? Do you use .cpp files at all?

Comment: Kinda back and forth, so I apologise for that.
No, I use the header file to declare the functions and the .cpp to define them.
If this is the wrong way to do it please explain why; instead of saying 'that's wrong'...

Comment: No that good. I thought you were defining and implementing the function in the header file while not using a cpp file for the implementation. You are doing the right thing. I am now installing visual c++ and visual studio to check if I can find out how it works in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.
Just so you are aware I'm using the 2010 version.
There are little variations in the IDE between versions but its probably best to let you know.

Comment: Yeah that'll be fine. Have you been able to locate your .lib file already?

Comment: How about we move to a chat?

Comment: Found it.
It was in the Debug file within the directory of my StaticLibrary.
So, what do I do with that?

Comment: You will have to link it with the application in which you are going to use it. I just made an application, so give me a few minutes.

Comment: Thought I was an idiot for a minute there ^^,
Do appreciate the help.
If you can't figure it out i'll ask a friend later-on; as he programs simulation engines, so he'd know - hopefully.

Sorry for occupying so much of your time.

Comment: You're too awesome!
Thanks mate.